# Where does Package.Name come from?

Tags: python

In the `add_packages` method below, is `[package.name]` just a variable name for the key? Where do we get `package.name` from?

```
 class Repository:
   def __init__(self):
     self.packages = {}
    def add_package(self, package):
     self.packages[package.name] = package
```

Comment: `package` is a parameter of `add_package`, and `name` is an attribute of it.

Answer (score 1):

`package.name` is an *expression*; the value of the expression is the value of the `name` attribute of whatever object `package` refers to. `package` is the name of a parameter of the `add_package` method. When you *call* this method, the value you provide as an argument is bound to the name `package`.

For example,

```
class Package:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


p = Package("foo")  # p.name == "foo"

r = Respository()
r.add_package(p)  # self.packages["foo"] = p
```

Comment: chepner
Thanks, so the name is going to come from the class Package.
In your example, the package key will be foo and its value is p.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. In this case, `Package` is just a simple class I defined to be able to create *some* object that has a `name` attribute. `Repository.add_package` itself doesn't care what type `package` has, as long as it has a `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much chepner.  I really appreciate your time.